# Python Altair transform_regression with binned data

Tags: python, data-science, visualization, altair

My problem is that I'm trying to visualize some data of the cars.csv containing the variables for age and mileage (kilometers). I want to visualize the relationship between both variables with regression lines. When I'm adding the bin parameter to set the classes for age and kilometer, it is not possible to show the regression line anymore. Maybe someone got a better idea for better visualisation.

```py
import altair as alt

scatter_plot = alt.Chart(sample).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('age', stack='zero', bin=True, sort='-y', axis=alt.Axis(labels=True, title='Age')),
    alt.Y('kilometer', bin=True),
    color=alt.Color('count():Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category10'), legend=alt.Legend(title='Count')),
    tooltip=["count():Q"]
)

scatter_plot + scatter_plot.transform_regression('age', 'kilometer').mark_line()
```

The output of code:

[image: output of code]

I deleted the bin parameter; it works well for regression but is a complete mess with all the different data points.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Altair is charting a binned version of the independent variable instead of the actual independent variable itself. When you tell the regression to use `age` as the independent variable, it doesn't show up on the chart because `age` isn't actually on that chart - the binned version is. So the question is, how do you reference a binned field in multiple places in the chart?

Per [Altair's Bin documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/bin.html), "If you are using the same bins in multiple chart components, it can be useful to instead define the binning at the top level, using `transform_bin()` method."

Your example should look something like this:

```
import altair as alt

scatter_plot = alt.Chart(sample).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('binned_age', stack='zero', sort='-y', axis=alt.Axis(labels=True, title='Age')),
    alt.Y('kilometer', bin=True),
    color=alt.Color('count():Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category10'), legend=alt.Legend(title='Count')),
    tooltip=["count():Q"]
).transform_bin(
    'binned_age', 'age'
)

scatter_plot + scatter_plot.transform_regression('binned_age', 'kilometer').mark_line()
```